Converting partizipal attribute into relativ Satz [Identifying which parts belong to the attribute]

Aufgabe: Convert into relativ Satz
Von den weltweit ca. 5 Milliarden Hektar landwirtschaftlich genutzen Flächen werden fast 80 Prozent durch die Viehwirtschaft beanpsrucht.

My attempt:
Von den Flächern, die weltweit ca. 5 Milliarden Hektar landwirtschaftlich genutzt sind, werden fast 80 Prozent durch die Viehwirtschaft beansprucht.
My identification of partizipal:
Von den [weltweit ca. 5 Milliarden Hektar landwirtschaftlich genutzen ] Flächen werden fast 80 Prozent durch die Viehwirtschaft beanpsrucht.
However, in the solution, it is written:

Von den weltweit ca. 5 Milliarden Flächen, die landwirtschaftlich genutzt sind, werden  durch den Viehwirtschaft beansprucht.

Is my solution wrong? If so, what is the mistake in my identification?

The problem is merely that your bracketing is not correct. "Hektar" is a surface measure, so it measures "Flächen", and then "landwirtschaftlich genutzt" also qualifies "Flächen", only the latter is the participial phrase.

Check the solution again please. That doesn't make sense.

Could you elaborate on the mistake? @Olafant

Relative clauses in general can qualify a noun but they can't quantify it. That's why the number needs to stick before the noun:

von den drei am Bahnhof stehenden Zügen
von den drei Zügen, die am Bahnhof stehen

but not

von den Zügen, die drei am Bahnhof stehen

Sometimes it's possible to rephrase it, albeit with different meaning:

von den Zügen, die zu dritt am Bahnhof stehen

That's about the trains which form a triplet at the station.

There's an exception from this general rule though. With verbs that measure, you can't build relative clauses that qualify a noun. But instead you can build one that quantifies it:

die alte drei Liter fassende Gießkanne
die alte Gießkanne, die drei Liter fasst

but not

die Gieskanne, die alt drei Liter fasst


And you may stumble across relative clauses that quantify nouns without such a measuring verb but it's super poetic:

von den Zügen am Bahnhof, die da drei sind

IIRC they translated the Holy Hand Grenade instructions in the rabid rabbit scene from Monty Python and the Holy Grail (German title: Die Ritter der Kokosnuss) that way.

The answer key is also not completely correct though, as it hasn't moved weltweit into the relative clause:

Von den fünf Milliarden Hektar Flächen, die weltweit landwirtschaftlich genutzt sind, …


You said: "Relative clauses cannot quantify a noun". I think they can. What about: "5 Hektar Fläche" = "Fläche, die 5 Hektar misst".  Or: "die landwirtschaftlich genutzten Flächen, die sich weltweit auf 5 Milliarden Hektar summieren" ?

I think those are well defined exceptions as their verbs are about measuring a number. You can't turn the qualifying members of the noun phrase into a relative clause with those verbs. — von der drei Liter fassenden alten Gießkanne → von der alten Gießkanne, die drei Liter fasst but NOT von der Gießkanne, die alt drei Liter fasst

I edited my answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

"von den Zügen derer drei am Bahnhof stehen..." für die besonders altmodische Art ;)
